# When using karma coverage with angular, some code is never ran

Tags: angular, karma-coverage

When using karma coverage with angular 2, some code is never ran and I would like to either execute it or exclude it.

For example:

```
if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
```

or

```
r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
```

Thanks for your help!